# Looking for template in a wrong directory

Tags: python, django, django-templates, openshift

I have uploaded my Django project to Openshift and python code works correctly, however, my templates are being loaded from a wrong folder:

```
/var/lib/openshift/55b9********************/templates
```

My settings.py file contains:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
)
```

which correctly points to

```
/var/lib/openshift/55b9********************/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/marko/templates
```

As shown in django's traceback page. Why could this be happening? I could copy my templates to the folder it looks for, but I'd rather not place any project files outside of the project folder. `runserver` on local machine looks for templates in correct folder.

Comment: Please show us how you initialize `BASE_DIR`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running Django 1.8? The `TEMPLATE_DIRS` directive is deprecated and replaced by `TEMPLATES`.

According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/) you should update your settings like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            # insert your TEMPLATE_DIRS here
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Assuming `BASE_DIR/templates` points to the right directory.